# Using numerical methods to calculate integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

$$
\mbox{How can I go about calculating}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}\,{\rm e}^{-100\,x^{2}}\,{\rm d}x\quad 
\mbox{to}\ {\sf\mbox{five}}\ \mbox{decimal places of accuracy ?.}
$$

Do I use Simpson's Rule ?. If so, wouldn't calculating the fourth derivative be a pain, and what about maximums ?.

Comment: I don't know if you're supposed to know this but $$\int_0^\infty{e^{-100x^2}}dx = \dfrac{1}{10}\int_0^\infty{e^{-u^2}}du = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{20}$$ which is around $0.08862$.

Comment: I have no experience with numerical integration of improper integrals, but I am thinking of two possible strategies: Do a substitution which makes the limits finite or split the integral in two parts so that the last one is less than $10^{-5}$.

Comment: You can use
[Gauss–Hermite Quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Hermite_quadrature).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we want to approximate:
$$ I = \frac{1}{10}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx $$
it is enough to have an approximation for:
$$ J = \int_{0}^{4}e^{-x^2}\,dx,\tag{1} $$
since:
$$ \int_{4}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = e^{-16}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-8x-x^2}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{8e^{16}}.$$
To achieve a good approximation for $(1)$, it is sufficient to integrate termwise the Taylor series of $e^{-x^2}$:
$$e^{-x^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^{2k}, $$
$$\int_{0}^{4}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k 4^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}.\tag{2}$$
By Leibniz' rule, we just need to find a $k$ such that:
$$\frac{4^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}<10^{-4}.$$
With some rather crude bound for $k!$, it is not difficult to prove that $k=50$ is enough, so:
$$ I \approx \frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=0}^{50}\frac{(-1)^k 4^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)k!}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Obviously this is far from the most efficient approach. Since we need just an approximation of $\pi$, a good approach is to use Machin's formula, the Taylor series of the arctangent function and a square root extraction.

Comment: An alternative approach is to compute $$\pi^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{18}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$$ by summing the first $10$ terms of the series, then taking the fourth root.

Comment: I approached this similarly. Since this question is tagged [tag:numerical-methods], it is good to avoid $\int_0^\infty e^{-100x^2}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{20}$ except as a check. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for answering first. I got a nice hat for deleting my answer ;-)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Did he drop the $(-1)^k$ by accident when doing the <10^-4 part....

Comment: @robjohn and why 10^-4 and not 10^-5 for five decimal places?

Comment: @CollegeConfidential: Notice that that estimate is going to be divided by $10$, so an error of $10^{-4}$ when divided by $10$ is an error of $10^{-5}$.

Comment: I think for my answer I'm supposed to compute that and find the actual decimal. How can I do that? @robjohn

Comment: @CollegeConfidential: Either Jack's formula $(3)$ or the formula in my deleted answer $$\frac1{10}\sum_{k=0}^{28}\frac{(-1)^k\,3^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)\,k!}$$ should give the result to $5$ decimals

Comment: Supposed to use simpson's rule